# Android: How to set "captive_portal_server","captive_portal_http_url","captive_portal_https_url" without use ADB?

Tags: java, android, captiveportal

My android SDK is API:25

I find an answer to set captive_portal_detection_enabled by use the code below.

So that,I can escape the exclamation mark  if it's in a walled garden.

```
 Settings.Global.putInt(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_detection_enabled", 0);
```

Now, I want to change three value with the code as above :

1. captive_portal_server
2. captive_portal_http_url
3. captive_portal_https_url

I use

```
 Settings.Global.putString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_server ", ServerList.get(position));
            Settings.Global.putString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_http_url  ", "http://"+ServerList.get(position)+"/generate_204");
            Settings.Global.putString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_https_url  ", "https://"+ServerList.get(position)+"/generate_204");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Captive portal server is now : " + server()
                                            +"\nCaptive portal http_url is now : "+http_url()
                                            +"\nCaptive portal https_url is now : "+https_url(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and I always get **null** of server(),http_url(),https_url().

```
    private String server(){
    return Settings.Global.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_server");
}
private String http_url(){
    return Settings.Global.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_http_url");
}
private String https_url(){
    return Settings.Global.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), "captive_portal_https_url");
}
```

Please help me to solve it !

By the way!!! How do I check the url is server or not?!!!